# IPTABLES - Port forwarding from tun0 to eth0

Tags: iptables, routing, vpn, openvpn

I have a VPN router (Raspberry Pi with Debian) which connects to the VPN on tun0.

I have a workstation connected to the Pi (eth0) which forwards outgoing traffic over the VPN

```
#enable forwarding (added to /etc/sysctl.conf)
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 


#route forwarded packets over tunnel
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I want to forward incoming traffic from my VPN to a specific application port 12345 on my workstation. I believe NAT will be involved. My VPN is configured to port forward to 12345 (IPTABLES logs show incoming request with DPT:12345).

This is where I'm confused.

I believe I need a PREROUTING rule such as

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i tun0 -p udp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination <WORKSTATION IP>:12345
```

The IPTABLES logs show that it's pushing incoming traffic to the workstation correctly.

However I'm not sure how to get the corresponding traffic *back out* again correctly.

I think it may involve a SNAT of some sort, but the incoming IP's are random, and their SRC ports are random.

Any help would be appreciated. ChatGPT seems to think that this should work, but it doesn't.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Been reading various forums and articles but I'm not sure what I should be Googling now!

Comment: If you have Netfilter problems then you should usually add your configuration to the question i.e.  the output of `iptables -nvL ; iptables -t nat -nvL`. I don't understand what you mean by `The IPTABLES logs show that it's pushing incoming traffic to the workstation correctly.`. Are the packets leaving the Raspi towards the workstation? `tcpdump -i eth0 -n host $workstation_ip and udp port 12345` would show that. Maybe the `FORWARD` chain blocks this redirection.